# How to pass parameters to a function being passed as an argument of addEventListener or being assigned to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

What is the correct and professional way to add parameters to a function being passed to `addEventListener()` or or being directly assigned to an event handlers as in `el.onclick = doSomething(param);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function when you need to pass parameters to another, like this:

```
el.addEventListener("click", function() { doSomething(param); }, false);
```

Whereas if it *didn't* need parameters, it would just be:

```
el.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
```